# Keep checking if condition is true

Tags: javascript

I have an if statement and would like to keep checking if the condition is true.

I looked up a solution for this and created the following:

```
var interval = 400;
var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
  if (wood > mainBuildingCostsWood.innerHTML) {
     alert('Works');
     window.clearInterval(timer);
  }
}, interval);
```

The code above should check if the user's current wood is more than 250. The wood counts up by 1 automatically. So after a while the user's wood should be over 250.

Unfortunately this code doesn't work, can anyone help me out on this one?

Comment: show some debug info here: console.log(typeof wood, typeof mainBuildingCostsWood.innerHTML)

Comment: I did a parseFloat on `wood` and made a new var for `mainBuildingCostsWood.innerHTML`. This makes both of them a number now, but still with no luck.

Comment: What "no luck" means? It's not a lottery but programming. What value is `wood`? What value is `mainBuildingCostsWood.innerHTML`?

Comment: It means that it still does not work. It's an expression.

Comment: What "does not work" means? How do you know it does not work?

Comment: The value of wood (as described in my post) is 250 (after a while) same as for the `mainBuildingCostsWood.innerHTML`, also "does not work" means that it shows not errors and does not show the alert which it should do after checking the condition.

Comment: @Chris it "works" for sure http://jsfiddle.net/89wyqybo/1/

Comment: @Chris "after checking the condition" --- which means the condition is false. Which means some of your *assumptions* about the state is *wrong*. So what you need to do is to check that *every variable* has the value you expect it to have, not guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by putting the 'changing' variables inside the interval function.

```
    var interval = 400;
    var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
      /* Current resources */
      var wood = document.getElementById('wood').innerHTML;
      var iron = document.getElementById('iron').innerHTML;
      var clay = document.getElementById('clay').innerHTML;

      if (wood > parseInt(mainBuildingCostsWood.innerHTML)) {
         alert('Works');
         window.clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, interval);
```

Comment: bad idea: DOM tree will be scaned on every interval iteration: 
document.getElementById(...)

Comment: Any idea for a better solution? :)

Comment: here some little references:
www.w3schools.com/js/js_performance.asp (Reduce DOM Access)
http://jonraasch.com/blog/10-javascript-performance-boosting-tips-from-nicholas-zakas

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` is a string while I'm guessing that `wood` is a number. Do a `parseFloat()` first.

Comment: Tried your solution, but unfortunately no luck.

Comment: `400 > '1.5'` yields true

Comment: @Chris - you need to do `parseFloat(mainBuildingCostsWood.innerHTML)`. `parseFloat()` converts from a string to a number. You need both sides of the `>` operator to be numbers. If one side is a string, then the other side gets converted to a string too and the two values are compared as strings. And there, of course `"2" > "12"`, for the same reason why `"b" > "ab"`.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that everything's fine with "scope":

```
var wood;
...
var mainBuildingCostsWood = document.getElementById("<your_element>");
mainBuildingCostsWood.innerHTML = 250;
...
var timer = setInterval(function(){
 if (wood > mainBuildingCostsWood.innerHTML) {
   alert('Works');
   clearInterval(timer);
 }
}, 400);
```

Comment: I've tried using 250 instead of `mainBuildingCostsWood.innerHTML` but this does not work either. Thanks for your post though!

Comment: @Chris why do you think it "should work" at very first place?

Comment: explore your wood value on every interval iteration: 
if (wood > mainBuildingCostsWood.innerHTML) { console.log(wood); ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt();` to convert `string` to `INT`

```js
var interval = 400;
var wood = 250;//
    var WoodCosts = parseInt(document.getElementById("mainBuildingCostsWood").innerHTML);//user wood
    var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
      if (wood > WoodCosts) {
         document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = 'Works';
         window.clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, interval);
```

```html
<div id='mainBuildingCostsWood'>20</div>
<div id='status'></div>
```

Comment: Which means that you assume that the value of `mainBuildingCostsWood` never changes. While OP's code checks its exact value every time.